# reading horizontal lines in file python

Tags: python

so i am trying to come up with a suduko checker code. Where the data required is stored in an external file. I am trying to check if the numbers match horizontally. so far i have the following

```
filename=input("Enter filename:-")

with open(filename) as f:  #opening files
    content = f.readlines()  #obtaining each lines  

for line in lines:             #check each line
    numbers=line.split()  #split each line    # split(example 135246 into 1,3,5,2,4,6 )
    newnumber=letter.sort()   #arrange to 1,2,3,4,5,6
    if newnumber=[1,2,3,4,5,6]:
         print("valid")
    else:
         print("not valid")
```

i was wondering if this would work to check the horizontal numbers

Answer (score 1):

```
filename=input("Enter filename:-")

with open(filename) as f:  #opening files
    for line in f:
        numbers = [int(i) for i in line.strip()]
        numbers.sort()
        if numbers == list(range(1,7)):
            print("valid")
        else:
            print("invalid")
```